# Is there any difference to instantiate a new MySqlConnection object VS pass in instantiated MySqlConnection object into the "using" statement in C#?

Tags: c#, dapper, database-connection

I am wondering if there is any differences in instantiating a new MySqlConnection object VS passing in an instantiated MySqlConnection object into the "using" statement in C#?

If yes, what is the preferable way? why is it preferable over the other?

Below is the sample code to simulate the two cases :-

```
public class QueryService() {
    private IDbConnection con;

    public QueryService() {
        con = new MySqlConnection(connectionString));
    }

    public List<ExampleDto> QueryList() {
        using (con)
        {
            con.Open();
            // Do work here; connection closed on following line.
        }
    }
}

public class QueryService() {
    public QueryService() {}

    public List<ExampleDto> QueryList() {
        using (var con = new MySqlConnection(connectionString)))
        {
            con.Open();
            // Do work here; connection closed on following line.
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you know what `using` means? What would happend if you call `QueryList` would be called twice in with your first code ?

Comment: As a general rule, keep the scope of disposable resources as small as possible, to minimize the chance of leaks. In your code, if `QueryService.QueryList` is never called (because an exception happens, for example) the connection is never disposed. As an even *more* general rule, keep the scope of *anything* you use as small as possible, disposable or not -- it makes code easier to reason about.

Comment: @Selvin Yes, I do know what `using` means, and yes, `QueryList` would be called more than once.

Comment: @JeroenMostert Are you suggesting the second code is a preferable way, to keep the scope of disposable resources as small as possible?

Comment: Yes. (This is assuming `MySqlConnection` implements connection pooling, like any sane database driver should.)

Comment: @Selvin Hhmm.. I guess because the question isn't asking what `using` means?

Comment: *I guess because the question isn't asking what using means?* .. *yes, QueryList would be called more than once.*  ... so it means **no ... you don't know what would happend** ... well, I will tell you ... [**you would use disposed object which will end with Exception**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.objectdisposedexception?view=netframework-4.8)

Answer (score 1):

"using" does the "Dispose" at the end of the using-scope.
So in both cases you end up, with a disposed connection.

But in the first case, you still have access to the already disposed variable.
This is not the recommended way, but it is allowed.

The only thing you are allowed to do with this disposed variable, is assigning a new value.
Anything else will fail. The content of the variable is not set to null.